# How to change the primary display at runlevel 3

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, virtual-console

I have a desktop with two screens attached to it's VGA ports (GPU and motherboard). My main screen has two input ports (VGA and HDMI). I often plug my laptop into the HDMI port on the main screen and switch the input mode so that the main screen displays the laptop's screen while the secondary is still controlled by the desktop.

The problem is that when the machine is at run-level 3 or in a virtual console the command line is always displayed on the primary monitor. So to use my desktop I have to change the input on the main screen back to the VGA port.

I would like to be able to use the command line on my secondary display. Is it possible to temporarily change the primary monitor via the command line?

Thanks